# Entity Framework and bindingNavigator.AddNew using details in WinForms

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a WinForms application, using EF6.1. I have bindingsource and bindingnavigator automatically populated on the forms. Doubleclicking a customer in a GridView leads me to a new form where I show details for this customer as details, with the option of adding new customers. The bindingsource has only one item and the context.Local likewise. Clicking the plus-sign in the navigator adds another customer, and the bindingsource now have two items to keep track of while context.Local still have only one. I need to make my context aware of this new record, but everything I've tried seem to add yet another record to the bindingsource. This will give me an exception when trying to save, as non-nullable columns are not populated. Code is like this:

```
   private void frmCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (context = new CarsEntities(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString))
        {
            customer = context.Customers.Find(Id);
            customerBindingSource.DataSource = customer;
        }
    }

    private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        context.Customers.Local.Add((Customer)customerBindingSource.Current);
    }


    private void customerBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var cust in context.Customers.Local.ToList())
        {
            if (cust.CustomerNo == null)
            {
                cust.CustomerNo = "8";//just for testing, will use a value from a sequence or something...
            }
        }
        customerBindingSource.EndEdit();
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is **context** to load DataSource and **context** to make SaveChanges point to different **contexts** in memory. According to **Programming Entity Framework** book by Julia Lerman,

> You’ll need to be aware of the fact that only the context that is
> tracking the changes is able to save them.  You can’t instantiate a new context and expect it to save changes to the entities that you’re working with in the form. It won’t know any- thing about them.
>
> Therefore, it is important to be sure that when you call SaveChanges, you are working with the same context you used to retrieve the data.

**Solution**

Instead of `using (context = new CarsEntities(...))` in the **form_load** method, just instiate the context like that `context = new CarsEntities(...);`.

Then, in the form_closing method, put `context.dispose();`.

**Code Sample**

```
private void frmCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    context = new CarsEntities(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString);
    customer = context.Customers.Find(Id);
    customerBindingSource.DataSource = customer;
}

private void frmCustomer_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    context.dispose();
}
```

Hope this solution help you.